# Display courses with at least 10 students

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have the following tables:

`Students (id, name, surname, study_year, department_id)`

`Courses(id, name)`

`Course_Signup(id, student_id, course_id, year)`

I want to display the courses to which at least 10 students have signed up for, only using subqueries (no group-by, join or set operations). This could be easily implemented using data aggregation and join:

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(csn.course_id)
FROM Course_Signup csn
JOIN Courses c
    ON csn.course_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.name
HAVING COUNT(csn.course_id) >= 10
```

But how would I do this only using subqueries? Is there any other way, other than `COUNT`, to get the number of courses? Thank you, in advance!

Comment: why? you could use SUM and CASE WHEN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query to retrieve the name:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT c.name FROM Courses c WHERE csn.course_id = c.id) AS name,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   Course_Signup csn
GROUP BY
       course_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
```

*Note: you should also `GROUP BY` the primary key the uniquely identifies the course as there may be two courses with the same name.*

If you also don't want to use `GROUP BY` then:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   Courses c
WHERE  10 <= ( SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM   Course_Signup csn
               WHERE  csn.course_id = c.id )
```

or, to also get the number of sign-ups:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM   Course_Signup csn
           WHERE  csn.course_id = c.id ) AS num_signups
  FROM   Courses c
)
WHERE  num_signups >= 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM Courses c
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM Course_Signup csn
  WHERE csn.course_id = c.id
) >= 10
```

which only uses a subquery and has no group-by, join or set operations.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TDWxz-zw)

If you wanted the actual count in the result set then you would need to repeat the subquery in the select list.

You might also need to do `COUNT(DISTINCT cs.student_id)` if there might be duplicates; particularly if the same student can sign up in multiple years - but then you might want to restrict to a single year anyway.